# Why is my code not taking the input for address?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct acho {
    char ahn[50], add[200];
    long int a, bal;
};

int main() {
    struct acho s;
    printf("enter name: \n");
    gets(s.ahn);
    printf("enter number: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &s.a);
    printf("enter address: \n");
    gets(s.add);
    printf("enter balance: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &s.bal);
    printf("Name: %s \n", s.ahn);
    printf("Account number: %ld \n", s.a);
    printf("Address: %s \n", s.add);
    printf("Balance: %ld \n", s.bal);
    return 0;
}
```

**Why isn't this code an taking input for address? Can anyone find the bug please?**
I have tried both input methods like `gets` and `fgets` but it is not taking input for address in any case.

Comment: Post exact input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%ld", &s.a);` does _not_ read an entire _line_, only up to the text that represents the number.  The following  `gets()` will read the remainder even if it is only `"\n"`.  Tip: use `fgets()` for all user input and not use `scanf()`.

Comment: Don't mix `gets` and `scanf`. BTW `gets` has been deprecated 20 years ago. Use `fgets` and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct acho {
    char ahn[50], add[200];
    long int a, bal;
};

int main() {
    struct acho s;
    printf("enter name: \n");
    fgets(s.ahn,50,stdin);
       printf("enter number: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &s.a);
    getchar();
    printf("enter address: \n");
    fgets(s.add,200,stdin);
    printf("enter balance: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &s.bal);
    printf("Name: %s \n", s.ahn);
    printf("Account number: %ld \n", s.a);
    printf("Address: %s \n", s.add);
    printf("Balance: %ld \n", s.bal);
    return 0;
}
```

1. use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`. gets() is inherently unsafe, because it copies all input from STDIN to the buffer without checking size. This allows the user to provide a string that is larger than the buffer size, resulting in an overflow condition.
2. your **address statement** is reading a newline character add a `getchar()` before `printf("enter address: \n");` to read a newline character.